# how to return code php/html into a variable

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

in class we need to make a own mvc framework in php.
I have a method that returns a view in two forms, the first one show it, and the second one give to a variable like content.
The problem is that in the load_view method for the second form, i used a `return require_once` but that makes the html code and everyting get showed when i dont wanna show it.

here is the `load_view` method:

```
function load_view($view, $data, $async){
    if (is_array($data)){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }

    if ($async) {
        return $tmp = require_once('aplication/view/'.$view.'.php');
    } else {
        echo require_once('aplication/view/'.$view.'.php');
    }
}
```

the controller that implements the method:

```
class user extends core_controller {

function __construct() {
   $this->data['css'] = array('public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                              'public/css/login.css' );
}

function action(){
    $this->data['content'] = $this->load_view('loginForm', array(), true);
    $this->load_view('templates/template', $this->data);
}
```

}

the views:
first: `template`

```
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
```

second: `loginForm`

```
        <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" action="login/enter" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" required>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button">Registrarme</a>
                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question

Comment: Why the `echo require_once('`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i get it here is the new code for the `load_view`

```
function load_view($view, $data, $async){
    if (is_array($data)){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }

    if ($async) {
        ob_start();
        include('aplication/view/'.$view.'.php');
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        @ob_end_clean();
        return $buffer;
    } else {
        echo include('aplication/view/'.$view.'.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file get contents instead of require

```
if ($async) {
    return file_get_contents("yourfile.php");
}
```

Comment: You may need to mess with it a bit, I am on mobile right now but file_get_contents should get the page html without printing it on the page